# pygame unknown module macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, pygame

I have pygame installed and pip3 installed. 
however, when I import pygame into the idle I am prompted with an unknown module.

I am trying to learn python but this situation is giving me a headache.

is there a way for my computer to find python files easier...

the path is all over the place.

in the terminal 
pip3 search pygame prompts me with the pygame content but when i go to import the module isn't there?

Comment: need to see your commands and code.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1. Is your file called `pygame.py`?
2. If you type `python3 -m pygame` does it say `Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html`?
3. Have you tried installing it again (`sudo pip3 install pygame`)?
4. Maybe try install it by `sudo pip3 install pygame --user`